# Sql Server class in C# for all request?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, class

I'm looking for a class for Sql Server. I need to make insert, update, delete, select (retrieve many rows and columns) and execute Stored Procedure.

I didn't find a sample of this sort of class and i didn't want to reinvente the wheel.

Somebody can give it to me?

Comment: Have you looked at SqlConnection and SqlCommand in System.Data.SqlClient ?

Comment: There are dozens of "wheels".  Here are two: [`SqlDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) and Entity Framework

Comment: Search the web using `ADO.NET`, `LINQ to SQL` and `Entity Framework` keywords.

Comment: Yes but i would to put all my data access in one object...

Answer (score 2):

You sound like you may be looking for a [ORM (Object Relational Mapper)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). There are a [great number available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET), some built right it to the .NET framework itself. Look at the various websites and see if you can find one that fits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

There's not a single class that does this, but instead a set of a few classes you need to know:

#### Sql Server specific:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
```

#### Used by all database types

```
System.Data.DataTable
System.Data.DataSet
System.Data.SqlDbType (enum)
```

There are others as well, but these are the main ones. Together, these make up the ADO.Net API, and the Sql Server provider for the ADO.Net API.

Additionally, there are a number of Object Relational Mappers that build on top of ADO.Net to try to make this easier. Entity Framework, Linq To Sql, and NHibernate are of a few of the more common options. One common characteristic of ORMs is that they try to free you from even knowing the sql language. If you want to write your own SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries, which it sounds like you do, you should start at the native ADO.Net level.

To put your data access in one object, you create your own class that makes use of these other types. Don't try to build a new public method that accepts an sql string. Build individual methods for each query you will want to run that include the needed sql as part of the method, and have those methods use these types to change or return data.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C).

There is builtin functionality (`System.Data.SqlClient`) to simply access an SQL server.

Comment: It is a ok tutorial, they don't discuss using `using` statements at all for the disposable connections. It does reference wrapping `Close()` in a try-catch but that is only to catch any exceptions returned from `Close()`, not to close in the event a exception happened between the opening of the connection and the closing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single class that can do everything you need. Whatever choice you decide you would necessarily need to deal with multiple classes.

Look at it this way – in order to get data from SQL Server you need to typically do following things:

- Open connection
- Crete SQL query
- Execute SQL Query
- Accept results
- Close connection 
  Putting all this functionality into a single class would make the class way too complex.

Here is a good reading material for what you need.

[Beginners guide to accessing SQL Server through C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C)